# Calling plain javascript in durandal.js

Tags: javascript, durandal, javascriptmvc

I am using durandal.js and i have to call some plguin on page load

this is what it would like in plain javascript

```
$('.testingShifter').shapeshift();
```

I just need to know is there any durandal(knockout) binding that i can use to call that javascript when page loads

Answer (score 2):

You can create an attached method in your viewmodel or you can create a custom binding for it.

e.g:

```
define(function () {

var vm = {
        activate: activate, 
        attached: attached 
}

var activate = function () {
    //Do vm activation here
};

var attached = function(view) {

        //do any dom stuff here.    
        var $testingShifter = $(view).find('.testingShifter'); 
        $testingShifter.shapeshift(); 
};
return vm;
```

});

OR

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.shapeShift= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        var $testingShifter = $(element);
        $testingShifter.shapeshift(); 

        });
    }
}
```

the custom binding handler would be called using:

```
data-bind="shapeshift:value"
```

on an html element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for scoping the attached callback to the view. Alternate syntax by using optional context instead of `find`.

`$('.testingShifter', view).shapeshift();` 

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context.

Comment: Yeah thats a nice way to do it to Rainer - Coincidentally ive been looking at your implementation of Durandal in sharepoint this week :)

Comment: Oldie, but goldie I hope. For a more recent example see http://rainerat.spirit.de/djODataAPIExplorer/