# Adding JQuery Calendar in MVC 4.0 John Papa hot towel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working on ASP.NET mvc 4.0 application using John Papa hot towel architecture.

I want to add a J Query Calendar control to my view.

I can place the the date picker in my html file.

how should i place the j query code which prompts the display of calendar on the click on user to the text box (i need to include the j query libraries but i dont know how to do it in Durandal Js.

this is how my javascript page looks like right now

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var title = 'Development Plan';

    var vm = {
       activate: activate,
       title: title
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate() {
        logger.log(title + ' View Activated', null, title, true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ive answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663011/calling-plain-javascript-in-durandal-js/20663488#20663488)

Make sure you include jquery ui in your bundle config. Then add a Attached (Durandal < 2 or viewAttached in Durandal 1.x) method to your viewmodel.

Hope this helps.